# Auto refresh and auto scroll up and down in one script

Tags: javascript, php, autoscroll

I already have separate auto refresh code and auto scroll code.

I want them to be in one function...How can I do that?

Here's my code for **auto refresh**

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function ()
{
  $('#load_tweets').load('http://myayg.com/index.php?route=salesTracker2.results').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);
```

and my **auto scroll**

```
function scroll(speed) {
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, speed, function() {
    $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
  });
}

speed = 30000;

scroll(speed)
setInterval(function(){scroll(speed)}, speed * 2);
```

I want them in one script...How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work....

```
function doRefreshAndScroll(speed) {
  $('#load_tweets').load('http://myayg.com/index.php?route=salesTracker2.results', function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, speed, function() {
      $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
    });
  }).fadeIn("slow")
}

var speed = 30000
setInterval(doRefreshAndScroll(speed), speed * 2)
```

Comment: Hi @Pranesh, your code has an error saying

index.php?route=salesTracker2.results:224 Uncaught ReferenceError: setIdoRefreshAndScroll is not defined

Comment: Hi, @Pranesh, it works but words are shaking...I think the codes are confuse

Comment: Did you test this one @Pranesh ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123514/discussion-between-pranesh-ravi-and-pink-widow-baby).